# Отметить checkbox по нажатию кнопки в wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую.

Наверное, не единожды заданный вопрос, но ответа на него найти не удалось.

Как можно отметить чекбокс по нажатию кнопки на форме? На конструкцию типа _8b.click = true; ругается, что не корректная формула, и нужен либо += либо -=.

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вполне возможно, что это единожды заданный вопрос. Все-таки перед тем, как работать с какой-либо платформой, нужно хоть немного ознакомиться с ней и ее возможностями. В частности, события принимают делегат на функция вызова, а не какой-то true. Присвоить true - это вообще что-то непонятное и выходящее за рамки простой логики.

Ладно, дело Ваше, просто более сложный код Вы не напишите наугад и подсказывать с таким уровнем понимания мало кто возьмется. По существу, все просто:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        кнопка.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(func_Click);
    }

    void func_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {

        чекбокс.IsChecked = true;
    }
```